# Send Java Class as function argument

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, .class-file

I want to pass a *Java* class as argument to a *Java method*.
The method is `getKeySpec()` of class `java.security.KeyFactory`:

```
getKeySpec(Key key, Class<T> keySpec)
```

The *NativeScript* Typings for this method is

```
public getKeySpec(param0: java.security.Key, param1: java.lang.Class<any>): java.security.spec.KeySpec;
```

How do I pass a `java.lang.Class<any>` to this method?
I want to pass `java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec`.

This is my current *TypeScript* code, which fails at the `getKeySpec()` call.

```
function getPublicKey(keyPair: java.security.KeyPair): string {
    const kf = java.security.KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    let pubKeySpec = kf.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec);
    return pubKeySpec.getEncoded();
}
```

Comment: "which fails" can you be more specific about that part? you can't send a "class", you can send either an instance of Class, or an instance of a class. Java has methods, not functions. Then again, it seems this is not java code, so why do you tag it as being Java?

Comment: The typescript compiler complains with the following: [ts] Argument of type 'typeof X509EncodedKeySpec' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Class<any>'.

Comment: Aha, seems to be valid according to typescript (which does not complain any more). I will test it later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like

```
let pubKeySpec = kf.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), X509EncodedKeySpec.class);
```